# The mechanism of pointers' subtraction

Tags: c, pointers

I have studied how math goes with pointers but there is a thing confusing me

for example :

```
int ages[]={10,20,30,40,50};
int* ages_ptr=ages;
for(ages_ptr;(ages_ptr-ages)<=4;ages_ptr++)
{
      printf("%d"*ages_ptr);
}
(ages_ptr-ages)<=4
```

here is my question how does result of ages_ptr-ages can be compared to int ?

Comment: A pointer is an `int` which is the memory location of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

This line: `int *ages_ptr = ages` is roughly equivalent to: `int *ages_ptr = &ages[0]`.

This means it it a pointer to the first element of the array. Actually, `ages == &ages[0]`.

When you write `ages_ptr++` it moves the pointer by `sizeof(int)` bytes, so to the *next* element of the array, so to `&ages[1]`, `&ages[2]` and so on.

Pointers are just numbers - say, for example, value of `&ages[0]` is `N`. It has `m` elements, so the last element is at the adress of `N + (m - 1) * sizeof(int)`.

Initially, value of `*ages_ptr` is `N` as well. On each iteration `i` it moves to `N + i * sizeof(int)`.

In the loop condition you have: `(ages_ptr - ages) <= 4`. This `4` is actually `m - 1`, which makes it `(ages_ptr - ages) <= m - 1`. By substitution, we get: `N + i - N <= m - 1`, so `i < m - 1`, which is `i < 4` in our case. (This `4` might be slightly misleading here, as coincidentally pretty often `sizeof(int) == 4` as well.)

Notice how `sizeof(int)` was dropped in the substitution - because we are dealing with the pointers, the values of addition / subtraction are automatically handled for us. If you write `a += x`, you mean *shift pointer `a` by x elements*. If `a` is `int *`, it actually means `a += 1 * sizeof(int)` *bytes*.

The same goes for subtraction - that's why `ages_ptr - ages` returnes number of *elements* between the two pointers, not number of bytes.